# read data from firebase and set the value of textview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

i faced an issue like user entered enrollment number and verify and read all data from that and set the value to text view
[image]

If user enter enrollment 66 then verify that enrollment and read all that data from 66 and set value of text view to marks of subjects.what i need to do if i want to solve Above problem?

I tried:

```
reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Marks");
reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String mm=dataSnapshot.child("mcad").getValue().toString();
        String jm=dataSnapshot.child("java").getValue().toString();
        String nm=dataSnapshot.child("nma").getValue().toString();

        txtmcadmarks.setText(nm);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If so, please show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you didn't try anything yet, I'd recommend getting started with the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start), [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/), or one of the many tutorials out there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have updated question see it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your Database Reference returns you a list of data so you need to receive your data as a list.

Second, if you want to filter your data base on `enrollment` then add a query in your database reference.

```
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = databaseReference.child("Marks").orderByChild("enrollment").equalTo(66);

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String mm=data.child("mcad").getValue().toString();
                String jm=data.child("java").getValue().toString();
                String nm=data.child("nma").getValue().toString();

                txtmcadmarks.setText(nm);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```